# Autofit fancybox after content load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I use fancybox to show some custom div. After showing the fancybox i call custom function that processes the div. The function changes the size of the content of the div and is third party.

So after calling it content is bigger than the fancybox was and scrollbars appear.

How to autosize fancybox manually to my content?

I call fancy like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox(
        {
            afterLoad   : function() 
            { 
             initializePuzzle();  
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What version of fancybox are you using?

Comment: @JasonSmall : the tag says fancybox-2  ;)

Comment: why i get minus 2? i dont understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$.fancybox.resize()` or `$.fn.fancybox.resize()` to resize the fancybox. Put this code after the related function execution.

Comment: I've put it after initializePuzzle function that generates the content but i have error that ...resize is not a function. How to fix it?

Comment: @tomaszs, can you provide your html mark up or some kind of demo.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan : the tag says fancybox-2 ... so `$.fancybox.update()` ... c'mon people, read the docs.

Comment: i used this: $(this).resize();